# Will there be any collision of data if we send/recieve data on same port using socket programming in c#?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am working on an application that has requirement to receive data and at the same time send data to the same address. It means at one time it will act as `TcpClient` and on the other it will act as `TcpListener`.

I am achieving this through sockets to send and receive data.

Please confirm and explain if there will be any data loss or data collision during the process of send and receive (Two way communication).

Comment: One you've opened a single socket connection between two endpoints, it already offers you the ability to both *send* and *receive* data using the same sockets.

Comment: I know the same. Just want to confirm that if there will be any collision of data if data will be sent and receive at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to worry.

You are using [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) whos purpose is to take care of the concerns you have raised.

What happens if data is lost or 'collides' as you have put it. Then TCP will take care of it and retry.